# How to get all the child element tag name and their values using xsl:for-each in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml like this,

```
<item-info>    
    <jid>CQG</jid>    
    <aid>498781</aid>    
    <ce:pii>10.10-88/0(26)49381-/0/0/000000</ce:pii>    
    <ce:doi>10.1088/02649381/0/0/000000</ce:doi>    
    <ce:copyright type="unknown" year="2014"></ce:copyright>    
</item-info>
```

And I am using xslt code.

```
<xsl:template match="item-info">
    <xsl:element name="item-info">
        <jid><xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/jid"/></jid>
        <aid><xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/aid"/></aid>
        <ce:pii><xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/ce:pii"/></ce:pii>
        <ce:doi><xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/ce:doi"/></ce:doi>
        <ce:copyright> 
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/ce:copyright/@type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>        
            <xsl:attribute name="year">
                <xsl:value-of select="/article/item-info/ce:copyright/@year"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </ce:copyright>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of mentioning each one what can I do to get all the child names and their values in single `xsl:value-of` select?

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Replace your whole template with `<xsl:copy-of select="item-info" />` ?

Comment: Have an identity template instead.

Comment: Your XSLT refers to an `article` element which is not in your XML. It might help if you showed a more complete XML sample, and also showed the output you were expecting. It does sound like using the identity template is the way to go here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform

Comment: Thank you, i really used

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it. I often use the copy and apply-templates of all child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="item-info">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You may also only select the childs you want:

```
<xsl:template match="item-info">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="jid|aid|ce:pii|cd:doi|ce:copyright"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```